# Simple CompletionItemProvider does not work

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm making my simple vscode extension and trying to implement a completion  item provider. I want to show an array of strings when typing the `|` sign in any file(no matter its extension).

The extension is written in JavaScript:

```js
context.subscriptions.push(...);
// other functionality above works ok
context.subscriptions.push(vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
  '*', 
  {
    provideCompletionItems(document,position,token) {
      item1 = new vscode.CompletionItem("Sample1");
      item2 = new vscode.CompletionItem("Sample2");
      return [item1,item2];
    }
  },
  '|'
));
```

I read a lot and can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

The suggestions menu that pops is empty and says "*No suggestions*":
[image]

Comment: have you set the kind of completion item? does the example extension work

Comment: Added the kind of completion item. This does not help.(((


`item1 = new vscode.CompletionItem('Sample1',vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text);
item2 = new vscode.CompletionItem('Sample2',vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text);`

Should I register/add the completion item somewhere else  besides the `context.subscriptions.push`?

Comment: Is the `provideCompletionItems` method executed at all?

Comment: I am not sure. How to check it?

Comment: set a breakpoint, set a logpoint, add some `console.log()`

Comment: Yes. The  method executes. However, it  begins to work even if another function from my extension is executed first. Then, the `provideCompletionItems` method works ok.

How to make the `provideCompletionItems` method executes when I run  the extension and start typing the `|` sign?

Comment: I mean the `activate(context)` function is not  executed if I run the extension, open a text file and start typing `|`.

Comment: I found the solution. Added the  `onStartupFinished` to the activation events. Thanks for HELP!!!